# visual studio 2010 doesn't remember ankkhsvn as being used as source control

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ankhsvn

I am using ankkhsvn (selected as an option in tools) in visual studio 2010 and when I restart my machine the project reverts back to Team foundation as the selected source control.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try this: Opent the solution, go to Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Choose Add-In, Choose "AnkhSVN" and save the entire solution. Check-In the code, restart your machine and try it again. Let me know if it works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click solution, add to subversion. confirm that you want to manage the .sln with subversion.

This adds a few lines to your .sln that enable AnkhSVN if it is installed (or are ignored if AnkhSVN isn't installed).